# How print data from browser in a local printer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, browser, printing, epl

I have a **.EPL file** generated from a [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) server, I need print this file in my local printer. Printing should be done automatically, eliminating **print dialog**. 
A chrome solution is enough.
Is there any plugin or something related that can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very unclear: what is an EPL file? (you tag it with EPL=Eltron Programming Language???). "I need print this file in my local printer" : language issues aside: who is "I" --you the programmer, or a user of your website. In other words, the "local" is a printer connected to your webserver, or a local printer a visitor of your website? The better you write your question, the better we can help you. Now it is a lot of guessing, and obviously you do not even appreciate the effort.

Comment: EPL is encoding accepted by Zebras printers. The printing will be done by the client that accesses my server, the printer is installed on your computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this](https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/) can help you. It's a plugin to print on browser with **Zebra Printers**.